# xdmp:document-insert not creating a new file

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have an XML located in some directory and i want to process and write a new file in target location but its showing `your query returned an empty sequence`?

XML:

```
<xpath>
    <toMultipleElement>TEXT 1.0</toMultipleElement>
    <toMultipleElement>TEXT 2.0</toMultipleElement>
    <toMultipleElement>TEXT 3.0</toMultipleElement>
    <toMultipleElement>TEXT 4.0</toMultipleElement>
    <toMultipleElement>TEXT 5.0</toMultipleElement>
    <toMultipleElement>TEXT 6.0</toMultipleElement>
    <toMultipleElement>TEXT 7.0</toMultipleElement>
</xpath>
```

xquery:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $input := xdmp:document-get("C:/Users/AmrendraG/Downloads/aaapp.xml")
  return 
     xdmp:document-insert("C:/Users/AmrendraG/Downloads/aaapp-out.xml", <root>{$input}</root>)
```

I want to write this file as aaapp-out.xml as same location.

Comment: I am new in xquery..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xdmp:document-get` is reading from the file system.
`xdmp:document-insert` is putting a document into the database.
If you want to write back to the file system, use `xdmp:save`.

Comment: Thanks @mholstege. I got the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

'xdmp:document-insert' inserts file to the database, if you want to save the file on local directory location use 'xdmp:save'.

Comment: furthermore, xdmp:document-insert will in fact return the empty sequence on success.  You should now see your 'file'as a 'Document' in MarkLogic where the URI of the document is as you specified (the full path name of the file on 'disk')